# How to give save dialog box by clicking on download button in php?

Tags: php

I am working on content based WAP application in which I will have to put
download button on selected content. Content can be (MP3,WAV,MP4,3gp,image). Content name is 9-digit random numeric character like `132432498.mp3`, `814274691.mp4`.
I tried below code

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['fileId'])){  
$fileid = $_GET['fileId'];  
{   
i retrieve content content path and name together 
like $filename="myserverip/1/3/4/132432498.mp3"   
}   
then  
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");   
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.";");    
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));     
 readfile($filename);       
exit;
?>   
< a  href= < ? php echo $filename; ?>>Download < /a> '
```

But file automatically gets downloading with name `132432498.mp3`.
I need help to write name of above content as I desire. How to do this in php?

Comment: Sorry, but this behavior (download without dialog box) concerns to Browser default action (client side). You cannot change this from PHP (server side).

Comment: the header handling the name is `header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.";");` i suppose you have a proper name in you db you can grab it from there and feed it in there

Comment: @PauloH. just wrote what I was going to say. This is all browser-dependent. You could create a link and advise users to  right click on it and select save as from the context menu. Alternatively, give them a text box to write the desired file name and use that to prepare the filename.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case you are providing a name with has spaces, you have to prevent that enclosing it with double quotes, like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```